# SQL query that does not include a unique column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I am trying to query for rows that only have a certain matching attribute so for example:

```
memID     name      SSN    
26        Dave      6    
26        Dave      6    
26        Dave      5    
5         Sean      8    
45        Ash       10    
45        Ash       29
```

What I want for my results are all the rows except:

```
5     Sean     8
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the matching attribute is.  Also, if you have tried a query then please include it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am working with a larger database so this is just a test case and not a literal case.  So I only want rows that have the same memID, with either possible matching names and SSNs.  I don't want rows that where the memID appears only once in the table.

Comment: You also have still forgotten to mention your logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE NOT memID=5
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
SELECT memID, name, SSN
FROM yourTable
WHERE memID IN (SELECT memID FROM yourTable GROUP BY memID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want rows where all the columns are unique -- they don't exist in other rows.  `exists` comes to mind:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.memid = t.memid or
                        t2.name = t.name or
                        t2.ssn = t.ssn
                 );
```

If you want rows where one or any of the columns are duplicates, then you want `exists` rather than `not exists`.

Comment: Hard to know, as a fellow mind-reader this *might* be right. It might be `and` rather than `or`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT Distinct memID, name, SSN
FROM tableName
WHERE memID IN (SELECT memID FROM tableName GROUP BY memID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query:

```
select * from Tablename 
where memid in(select memID from Tablename group by memID having count(*)>1)
```